# Airtable to WooCommerce product category issue syncing

Tags: woocommerce, airtable, pipedream

Workflow is:

Airtable - Holds product data
PipeDream - send data to WooCOmmerce
WooCommerce - Website/eCommerce

I'm able to sync pretty much all product data to WC, without issue. The problem faced is:

When a record is either a/ amended or b/ created in Airtable, the following does not work:

a/ New product categories are not created in WooCommerce

b/ Amendments to a product category it has are not reflected in WooCommerce, as in if they are removed they still show - if added, do not show

c/ Default category is always used

Sure this must be an issue discussed, but unable to find a solution to the issue.